# Timeline uses 12-hour notation without AM/PM indicator

Tags: bug, status-completed, timestamps, timeline

All [timelines for questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/119172/timeline) show time in 12-hour notation, but without AM or PM. That's slightly confusing, though the tooltip shows the correct details:

[image: Timeline shows 09:51 for 21:51]

Shouldn't the time use 24-hour notation instead?

Comment: The timeline also doesn't show the username next to comments, so. :P But yeah, that's pretty confusing.

Comment: That surely is much more confusing/annoying, @Tim!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, that's a bug (`hh` should be `HH` on a `.ToString()`)...it'll be fixed in the next build.